# Error dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher - Code signing error

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, gtmsessionfetcher

I am having this error with *GTMSessionFetcher*
I'm not sure what it means.
Could it be a could signing error?

```
    dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher
          Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/E62297DC-9AD6-49C8-8821-5F9BF265B7CF/Studioso.app/Studioso
          Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
            /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E62297DC-9AD6-49C8-8821-5F9BF265B7CF/Studioso.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E62297DC-9AD6-49C8-8821-5F9BF265B7CF/Studioso.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher'
            /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E62297DC-9AD6-49C8-8821-5F9BF265B7CF/Studioso.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E62297DC-9AD6-49C8-8821-5F9BF265B7CF/Studioso.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher'
            /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E62297DC-9AD6-49C8-8821-5F9BF265B7CF/Studioso.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E62297DC-9AD6-49C8-8821-5F9BF265B7CF/Studioso.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher'
            /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E62297DC-9AD6-49C8-8821-5F9BF265B7CF/Studioso.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E62297DC-9AD6-49C8-8821-5F9BF265B7CF/Studioso.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher'
            /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E62297DC-9AD6-49C8-8821-5F9BF265B7CF/Studioso.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E62297DC-9AD6-49C8-8821-5F9BF265B7CF/Studioso.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher'
        Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 6
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your code signing configuration (certs, profiles, etc) as indicated by `code signing blocked mmap()`.

Comment: I came across this issue recently and what worked for me was this -> Go to Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries > select GTMSessionFetcher.framework. Set it to Optional (instead of Required). Thats it. Clean your project and build/run again. Here's link to issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3586

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been facing the same problem... It got fixed by adding:

In you podfile:

`use_modular_headers!`

instead of

`use_frameworks!`

Good luck! I hope this works for you!