# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher SIGABRT

Tags: swift, xcode

The application runs on all other simulators and devices except my own.

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher   Referenced
>   from:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EA88F6D8-9D62-465E-A106-CF1198B06F3E/LeafLabel.app/LeafLabel
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EA88F6D8-9D62-465E-A106-CF1198B06F3E/LeafLabel.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher:
>   code signature invalid for
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EA88F6D8-9D62-465E-A106-CF1198B06F3E/LeafLabel.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher'
>
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EA88F6D8-9D62-465E-A106-CF1198B06F3E/LeafLabel.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher:
>   stat() failed with errno=25
>     /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EA88F6D8-9D62-465E-A106-CF1198B06F3E/LeafLabel.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher:
>   code signature invalid for
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EA88F6D8-9D62-465E-A106-CF1198B06F3E/LeafLabel.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher'
>
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EA88F6D8-9D62-465E-A106-CF1198B06F3E/LeafLabel.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher:
>   stat() failed with errno=1
>     /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EA88F6D8-9D62-465E-A106-CF1198B06F3E/LeafLabel.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher:
>   code signature invalid for
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EA88F6D8-9D62-465E-A106-CF1198B06F3E/LeafLabel.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher'
>
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EA88F6D8-9D62-465E-A106-CF1198B06F3E/LeafLabel.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher:
>   stat() failed with errno=1

[image]

Comment: You can find a possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685904/i-cant-fix-dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-gtmsessionfetcher-framework-gtmsess

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing the same problem... It got fixed by adding:

In you podfile:

`use_modular_headers!`

instead of

`use_frameworks!`

Good luck! I hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to apple not supporting external frameworks since 13.3.1, if you don't have a developer license.

Try the actions mentioned here: [Running iOS apps causes runtime error for frameworks "code signature invalid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015309/running-ios-apps-causes-runtime-error-for-frameworks-code-signature-invalid)